# gimp exports are about 50% bigger, how should I economize on space?

Tags: gimp, jpeg

Suppose I'm satisfied with the quality of a JPEG photo but I just want to crop the edges without ending up with a bigger file. I use gimp to do the cropping. The JPEG photos are always photos of text documents and in colour.

The resulting exported file typically is about 50% bigger. How should I prevent this? I am asking how I "should" prevent it; not how I can prevent it because I know I can just export at a lower quality but I don't want to dabble with a trial and error process and find sometimes the quality loss is too severe.  In other words, I don't want to have to check the result every time.  I would like a process that doesn't worsen the image quality and doesn't make the file bigger. This is theoretically possible since a cropped image does have less data.

I don't care about colour fidelity much as long as it is not obviously unfaithful to the original colours.  When the image is first loaded there is this dialog...

[image: dialog convert or keep]

Regardless of whether I respond to this dialog with 'convert' or 'keep' the document file ends up about 50% bigger. I always export with the same file extension so the document type, which is usually JPEG is unchanged. I always use the default 90% export quality.

Comment: What is the source of these images? Because for one program quality 90 may mean one thing, for other - other.

Comment: And from triangle - disk space, number of images, image quality  you can choose only two!

Comment: @RomeoNinov The images are from Skype using a phone camera. This (Skype, phone) might not be relevant because once the image is loaded into gimp, the 90% export quality probably means 90% of the quality gimp has available after color conversion and cropping.

Comment: IMHO skype do not make good images and image quality in skype is under 90. When you set in Gimp 90 you increase the size (not the quality) of the image. And do you really need to use Gimp?

Answer (score 0):

There's a pref to stop Gimp asking about colour profiles at import, under Colour Management.

[image]

When re-saving as another jpg, Gimp doesn't pay any heed as to what the image quality/compression was at import - that's all been discarded.

If you want to keep approximately the same data size per image size, you need to discover roughly what the previous compression value was, even if that's by trial & error. Note, you're still going to lose quality twice, because there's no way to undo the loss from the first compression. Saving at 90% the second time will lose less that saving at 50% - though as you noticed by increasing file size. Each new save after editing is a new loss in quality, unrelated to the last [except for some pattern-finding which may be repeated, too complex to go into here].

Answer (score 0):

If you say these images are scans of text (also by Skype), then the most data volume for storage goes to the variations of white in the paper background (by natural paper pattern, see through of the backside, pixel noise and JPEG-artifacts of the input file). Also the multiple variations of "almost black" are not required in text document.

After importing and cropping the image you should remove the lightest and darkest colors by adjusting the curve:

[image]
*This is the profile  of a typical colored text document with the reverse side slightly shining through.*

Strongly depending on the content (i.e. no pictures or rastered logos) the PNG file format might be smaller than JPG after this and further simple optimiziation (remove transparency/alpha channel , convert to indexed colors, minimized meta information)
But for general use at slagged optimization, in the average JPEG will be more convenient than PNG.

If you expect post processing of the image, try not to use comression at the time of creation. If possible (try to get PNG format) Only at the last step of processing use compression to obtain the best quality of the image at reduced filesize.

As the others here already stated:
When saving an image, in your use-case and quality expectations (1) you should omit the color profile (2) use an adequate JPEG-compression probably about 70 to 75%.

If you do this in a frequent manner you could use command-line tools or smaller GUI-tools having similar results, handsome automation and batch processing.